# Testflight cannot distribute app after pulling app down?

Tags: ios, store, testflight

everyone. I'm new in TestFlight.
I was going to distribute an app on app store but my customer regret and he wants to distribute by himself.
Then I pulled the app out of app store.
However, my customer still wants to test the app and I thought maybe I could use Testflight.
But App store has already examined for over three days.
In my experiences before, testflight examination cost even less than a day.
I'm wondering whether I cannot use this app account to distribute testflight?
Here's status of the app:

[image]

Comment: what is the status, "waiting for review"?

Comment: You might want to translate it to english.

Comment: oh, sorry. I should translate to English. The app status has been "waiting for review" for over three days.

Comment: Is it possible that it's thanksgiving holiday right now?